# Form validation problems

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a very strange problem. Inside form I have hidden input with value -1 and input field for username.

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="login" onSubmit="return Validate()">
  <input type="text" id="username"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="available" value="-1"/>
<  input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

On submit function Validate() checks value of `username` input which mustn't be empty, and Validate() also checks value of `available` input which mustn't be valued -1.

```
function Validate(){

var a=document.getElementById("username").value;
var b=document.getElementById("available").value;

if(a=="" || a==null)
{
    alert("Username cannot be empty");
    return false;
}
else if(b<0)
{
    alert("Form isn't finished");
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

Problem is that Validate() works only if one condition is evalueted. If function Validate() contains only 1 var(a or b) and 1 if order(without else if) it works correctly. But when I put it like this, when Validate uses a and b variables and if, else if conditional order it won't work. Really od.. Thanks in advance...

**In this case it works:**

```
function Validate(){

var a=document.getElementById("username").value;

if(a=="" || a==null)
{
    alert("Username cannot be empty");
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Seems ok. What you mean by *doesn't work* ?

Comment: it sends data to php file, even it shouldn't pass the validation... very odd... if validate is written as 2 functions, it works for both conditions, but in one function it doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="available" value="-1"/>
```

Here the value is of string dataType.  Whereas

```
else if(b<0)  //b is string dataType
```

Hence it failed.  so change it as

```
var b= Number(document.getElementById("available").value);
```

---

Try like this 
**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="login">
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <input type="hidden" id="available" value="1" />
    <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="return Validate()" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function Validate() {
    var a = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var b = Number(document.getElementById("available").value);
    if (a == "" || a == null) {
        alert("Username cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (b < 0) {
        alert("Form isn't finished");
        return false;
    } else {
        document.login.submit();  //dynamically submit the form
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but what about first condition, even if I left username input empty id doesn't alerts me as it should it...

Comment: wont the type coercion kick in here, "-1" is less than 0, so `b<0` should be fine. The only time it will fail is if it is not an actual number like if contains letters etc, then even your `Number` will fail as it will be NaN which is not less than 0

Comment: @PatrickEvans right, I thought it as edge case.  However I modified to the code to submit the form dynamically button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to get error notifications for each input don't use if/else here, use multiple if's and set your errors

```
function validate(){
   var a=document.getElementById("username").value;
   var b=document.getElementById("available").value;
   var errors = [];

   if(a=="" || a==null){
      errors.push("Invalid username");
   }
   if(b<0 || isNaN(b)){
      errors.push("Invalid available value");
   }
   if(errors.length>0) {
      //do something with errors (like display them
      return false;
   }
}
```

Using the else if one of them evaluates to true it will skip the others. For instance if the first one is empty or null then it will do that block and skip the others.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing your code for IE and Firefox and it work. Just add parseInt when you get the value of var b.

```
var b= parseInt(document.getElementById("available").value);
```